# What's the difference between "time" and "time_point_sec"?

Tags: smart-contract, c++

Seems that they are both datatype for storing number of seconds that have elapsed since 1970.
So what's the difference between them, when should I use which?

Edit:
An example of the "time" datatype I'm referring to can be found here: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosio.system/delegate_bandwidth.cpp#L65

Comment: time_point_sec is a type in the fc namespace, but what is the "time" datatype to which you refer? Do you mean "time_t" in <ctime>?

Comment: @James Mart For example in this contract (https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosio.system/delegate_bandwidth.cpp#L65), it uses a "time" datatype, not sure what's the difference between "time" and "time_point_sec".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`time`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/75635168e743c3e65bb6345a1eaedd905581e6b0/contracts/eosiolib/types.h#L44) is just a `typedef` for `uint32_t`, so it has no time-related functionality or restrictions¹ as long as you don't try to represent milliseconds (which you will need if you try to represent block time, as blocks are created every 500ms,) and it's very light to use inside smart contracts, but it doesn't play nice with other time types in `eosio`.
- [`time_point_sec`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/ff478bbd254649aa5e0a3222284884d0e7aaac70/contracts/eosiolib/time.hpp#L61-L109) is one of the `eosio` native time types--it's a class that implements several methods related to Unix Epoch time, and it's compatible interacting with other time types (e.g. `microseconds` and `time_point`.) It is very similar to [`time_point`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/ff478bbd254649aa5e0a3222284884d0e7aaac70/contracts/eosiolib/time.hpp#L38-L59) but it has no support for milliseconds, so it can't be used for EOS's sub-second blocktimes. In the past, it was suggested that [it should be removed](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/pull/2897#pullrequestreview-118965877), but it's still around for now. Dan [recommended](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/2890) that the ABI should use `time_point`, `time_point_sec`, and `block_timestamp` instead of `time`.

---

¹ Well, it has the restriction that it cannot represent timepoints beyond year 2106 by its nature of only using 32 bits